# Referencing Ashx Web Service - Use a Web vs. Service Reference?

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I am trying to add a service reference to a VB.NET forms project.  I am getting the following error when I try to create a reference to the webservice:

"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ApplicationName.Application Web Service' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."

I have researched this and discovered that I could be missing a System.Model element in the app.config file.  Is this correct? Should this element be automatically generated?

I found the error described here: http://www.socalmp.com/blog/template_permalink.asp?id=122

****Update 29/06/2012 at 21:30 GMT****
I managed to get this to work by adding a web reference instead of a service reference.  I understand the basic difference between a web reference and a service reference i.e. a web reference is a wrapper around wsdl.exe and a service reference is a wrapper around svcutil.exe.  Therefore if you add a ASHX web service then must you add a web reference and vice versa?

Comment: Does your VB.NET "forms project" expose a WCF service at all?  This seems odd...

Comment: @jonnygold, No the web service is exposed by an ASP.NET web service.  I am trying to consume the web service in the VB.NET project.

Comment: Ah - I read your first sentence wrong... need more coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You question misses few important informations.

E.g Have you ported the same on local host and is WCF service?

Can you test the URL in Browser?

Can you please provide more details on this?

You can check the [basic steps](http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/09/creating-and-consuming-a-web-service-using-visual-studio-net/) to see how to create webservices and consume it using visual studion .net.

Comment: I can browse to the web service in the web browser.  It is an ASHX web service.

Comment: Have you configure the Webservices in localhost? Please host the services in localhost and then try adding it....

Comment: @ Developer Jigar Pandya, it is a localhost on my development PC.